Film which has an insane father and son try to kill family all for dead wife
1980's or 1990's movie. Language is English and I think made in the US.
I think the family consisted of a father, mother, a son and daughter. I think the house where the family, and the insane father and son, are living is near a lake. 
Story Points:

One scene of the movie has the insane father talking with his heavily decayed wife. The wife is in a coffin and apparently in a wedding dress or something. Apparently, the wife is sad that the protagonists are living in their house and wants them out. Also, two corpses of a man and woman are standing near the coffin, and apparently are the wife's company. The scene ends with the father kissing the corpse.
Another scene has the father and son preparing for the killings, and the father tells the son to kill "for his mama".
One scene has the family running in the woods to try and escape. 
Approaching the end, the father attacks the family, but is then killed. The son tries attacking them, but is restrained when help arrives (the son, I think, begins sobbing)

